# How to change camera position/walk in aframe vr with accelerometer?

Tags: aframe, webvr

(I know it will be unstable but I still want to try it)

I want to move around in aframe scene using accelerometer

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent('acccam',{
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(){
            var acc = event.acceleration;
            this.el.object3D.position.x += acc.x*9.8;
            this.el.object3D.position.y += acc.y*9.8;
            this.el.object3D.position.z += acc.z*9.8;

        }, true);
  })
```

I expect the camera to move or at least shake/something but nothing is happening could getelement by id, get attribute and set attribute be used to update the position by taking temporary values and then cloning them if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the event is firing, and make sure you don't have like `look-controls` also enabled on the same entity or it will be overridden.

You can need to make sure `this` is the correct pointer. When you wrap in `function ()`, `this` becomes `window`. You can use `(evt) => {` instead of `function (evt) {`

Comment: can this be added to look-controls itself? if yes then how?

Comment: Copy the `look-controls` code and modify it to derive your own `my-look-controls` component that you would use instead